# CS0433 Error - The type "ClassName" exists in both "foo1.DLL" and "foo2.DLL"

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dll, .net-4.0

I want to publish my site again after making changes from visual studio but now it is not publishing. So I upload the files manually but **CS0433** error is coming. You can check it here http://roomrentkota.com/.

I have read the other solutions and applied the following:

- Deleted all the files from the error path
- Made changes in `web.config` file `batch="false"`

But still the error is there. Help.

**Edit 1**

I want to show slightly same content on two different domains so I copy the first folder and made the required changes in it and then uploaded both on hosting service and then the error arrise but then I deleted one of the files still the error is there.

**Edit 2**

Got the problem. Actually it is not my temporary files that are creating probem but the server's temp files. Now I want to know how can I delete the server temp files.

Comment: @Aayushi....can you show some code here and describe the problem.

Comment: The problem appears on every class that I have created in my Business Logic Layer. You can check the above link.

Comment: The type 'DetailsBLL' exists in both.... Clear your temp files.

Comment: @Ryan - As already said, I have cleared all the files from the error path.

Comment: @Aayushi you need to recheck all the things.....I think there are some reference problem and check the project property also.

Comment: @vikky - Where can I check project property?

Comment: refrence of DetailsBLL class is coming from two Dlls. try after deleting temp files

Comment: i think DetailsBLL  class is defined in two class library. where you are delcaring DetailsBLL object also use namespace from which you want to use class like namespace.DetailsBLL objDetailsBLL =new namespace.DetailsBLL();

Comment: i think deleting temp files from server will not work

Comment: The site is running perfectly on localhost, it is creating problem only when it is hosted.

Comment: here is the link for deleting temp files   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/12a84d42-c2db-4908-8161-9383c5b91003/how-to-delete-recent-prefetch-and-temp-items-in-system-using-c

Comment: Will it delete temp files on server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36111/discussion-between-chetanya-gehlot-and-aayushi-jain)

Comment: @AayushiJain Faced this issue long back,about the issues is `web.config`,After the deployment of the project,there another web.config file is still there in server cache and  and conflicts came due to that.Delete the temp and restarting the server helped us.